# Create GSI in DynamoDB for JSON Objects - AWS Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is it possible to create Global secondary index on JSON objects?

for example:

UserId: uuid
CreatedDate: timestamp
Details: Map

and Details will be:

`{"name":"Alex","age":40,"weight":"70"}`

I want to make a query on age property. Is it possible? if yes how we can create it on AWS Console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't create a GSI on JSON Objects. The AWS documentation states:

> Each index key attribute must be a scalar of type String, Number, or Binary. (It cannot be a document or a set.)

This is the link to the documentation page https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.OnlineOps.html#GSI.Creating.